# Rails page not showing in Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I deployed a simple Rails project on Heroku and I'm having some trouble. I set my root page as:

```
root 'landing#index'
```

This page works fine when I `cd` into the project, and start `rails server` and go to `localhost:3000`. I pushed to Heroku without error using `git push heroku master`. However now, if I do `heroku open`, I get the following message on the page:

```
The page you were looking for doesn't exist.

You may have mistyped the address or the page may have moved.
```

The logs don't show anything significant as well...

Comment: Can you post the routing error message?

Comment: There is none, and if there is, where can I find it?

Comment: heroku logs should return any errors that occur on the live server.

Comment: from you console run heroku logs -t and refresh the page. If something is wrong, you will probably get some hints there.

Comment: I get this log, it's just a 404... `2014-01-15T18:47:18.514207+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=
mighty-hollows-1981.herokuapp.com fwd="71.6.55.146" dyno=web.1 connect=7ms servi
ce=15ms status=404 bytes=1351`

Comment: What says the `heroku logs`?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have the following:

- A LandingController
- A view page at the path `app/views/landing/index.html.erb`
- `root 'landing#index'` on the second line (after Application.routes.draw)
- The live repository is up to date

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails4#write-your-app

Failing that, run `heroku run rake routes`. You should see a route like `GET /landing/index landing#index` and `root / landing#index`

If they don't appear, add the line `resources :landing` to generate the default routes for the landing controller.

Comment: Yes, I've ensured all of this.

Comment: Can you add the result of the rake routes command, the LandingController code and the contents of your routes file to the question? There might be something we're overlooking.